# Check checkbox if following label value is correct

Tags: katalon-studio, katalon-recorder, katalon

I got a user administration and want to check the checkbox before the label with 'test'. The checkbox and label are seperate from eachother. I can't use //input[@type='checkbox'])[3] because the checkbox and label can appear on a different row.

```
checkbox         user
checkbox         bla
checkbox         trying
checkbox         test
```

html of checkbox: `<input type="checkbox" class="ant-checkbox-input ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched">`

html users: `<app-userprofile-title _ngcontent-ads-c205="" _nghost-ads-c77="" class="ng-star-inserted">test</app-userprofile-title>`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this Xpath

```
//input[@type='checkbox']//*[contains(., 'test')]
```